# How Do I Indent My Proofs in the Following Manner?

Tags: formatting, indentation, theorems

I'm interested in indenting my proofs so that they look like this. Please note that the alignment of the word "proof" with the word "theorem" is significant. However, Google does not appear to yield an answer.

```
Theorem: If there is a quadratic form that is Lipschitz then there is an isotropic 
         manifold locally resembling ℍ[x] in the quotient of Ker(ϕ) and ℍⁿ ⊗ G

  Proof: Let ψ be a square-summable sequence in the rational quotient group. A simple
         application of trichotomy completes the proof, which is left as an exercise for
         the reader.
```

Comment: Should all the blocks like this one on the same page be aligned to the same width (e.g. Proposition: would be significantly longer)?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you added an MWE (minimum working example) to your question, to show us what you've done far. If you use packages such as `ntheorem` or `amsthm` that provided methods for formatting theorem-like environments, please be sure to mention that in the MWE as well.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Long indented proofs (with a very large indent if the tag is "Proposition") will spoil the page appearance.

Comment: On second thought, egreg's comment made me no longer made me desire this kind of formatting.

Comment: perhaps you'd like to put the work `Theorem` and `Proof` in the margin, in which case, [Examples enumerated in the margins](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101036) may help

Answer (score 3):

I know the OP no longer wishes to use this formatting, but in case anyone else is interested I used something like the following to align entries in my CV. It could also be applied here.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[2]{%
    \par\addvspace{\baselineskip}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.19\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            \textbf{#1}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.79\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft}
            #2
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \par\addvspace{\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]

\mycommand{Theorem:}{If there is a quadratic form that is Lipschitz then there is an isotropic manifold locally resembling $\mathbb{H}[x]$ in the quotient of Ker$({\phi})$ and $\mathbb{H}^{n}\otimes G$}

\mycommand{Proof:}{Let $\psi$ be a square-summable sequence in the rational quotient group. A simple application of trichotomy completes the proof, which is left as an exercise for the reader.}

\mycommand{Proposition:}{Some proposition}

\lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A list like structure is a better option, because it can break across pages.

Comment: Ah, good point.